# Whole page is flickered and jump to top when a part of the state is updated in react-redux application

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my react-redux application, I can properly update some data through an interface as you may see in the gif below. Below is the corresponding code where the redux state is changed:

```
case UPDATE_COMMENT_SUCCESS:
        const commentUpdated = action.payload.normalizedData;
        return {
            ...state,
            loading: false,
            editing: false,            
            discussionPosts: {
                ...state.discussionPosts,
                [commentUpdated.id]: {
                    ...state.discussionPosts[commentUpdated.id],
                    content: commentUpdated.content
                }
            }
        };
```

[image]

Below is the onclick evennt of the button clicked:

```
const onSubmit_updateComment = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    props.updateComment({
        Id: st_activeCommentToEdit,
        Content: st_commentTextEdit,
        UserId: currentUserId
    });
    set_activeCommentToEdit('');
}
```

Here is the form, that triggers the `onSubmit_udatecomment` event:

```
 <form onSubmit={onSubmit_updateComment} className="mt-2">
     <div className="form-group">
         <textarea
             defaultValue={props.comments[commentId].content}
             value={st_commentTextEdit}
             className="form-control"
             onChange={onChange_commentTextEdit}
         />
     </div>

     <div className="float-right">
         <button className="btn btn-sm btn-info" type="submit">Update</button>&nbsp;
         <button
             className="btn btn-sm btn-light"
             type="reset" onClick={(e) => { e.preventDefault(); set_activeCommentToEdit(0) }}>
             Cancel
         </button>
     </div>
     <div style={{ clear: 'both' }}></div>
 </form>
```

Below is the code where the database is updated (i.e., `props.updateComment` from the code below):

```
export function UpdateComment(commentData) {
    return dispatch => {

        dispatch(dataOperationBegin());

        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'api/AssessmentDiscussionPost/Update',
            data: {
                Id: commentData.Id,
                Content: commentData.Content,
                PostOwnerId: commentData.PostOwnerId
            }
        })
            .then(response => {
                console.log('success: Updated the comment');
                console.log(response.data);

                dispatch(updateCommentSuccess(response.data));

                toaster.notify('Comment is posted successfully.', {
                    duration: 2000
                })
            })
            .catch(error => { dataOperationFailure(error) });
    };
}
```

I tried without `toaster.notify` but the same problem persists.

Here is the code in the main component where the data is loaded for the first time:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (props.loading == false)//when the loading is complete
    {
        props.fetchReviewAlignPerspectivesdCardData(submissionId);
    }

}, [submissionId])
```

Here is the mapping the dispatch to the props:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
   return {
       fetchReviewAlignPerspectivesdCardData: (submissionId) => dispatch(FetchAlignPerspectivesData(submissionId)),
         }
}
```

Moreover, the `FetchAlignPerspectivesData` function that makes the axios call to the database is below:

```
export function FetchAlignPerspectivesData(submissionId) {
    var url = 'api/x/y';

    return dispatch => {

        dispatch(alignPerspectivesDataOperationBegin);

        axios.get(url, { params: { submissionId } })
            .then(response => {

                const alignPerspectives = new schema.Entity('alignPerspectives');
                const assessments = new schema.Entity('assessments');
                const discussionPosts = new schema.Entity('discussionPosts');
                const childPosts = new schema.Array(discussionPosts);
                discussionPosts.define({
                    childPosts: [childPosts]
                });

                alignPerspectives.define({
                    assessments: [assessments],
                    discussionPosts: [discussionPosts]
                });

                const normalizedData = normalize(response.data, alignPerspectives);
                dispatch(fetchAlignPerspectivesCardSuccess(normalizedData))
            })
            .catch(error => { alignPerspectivesDataOperationFailure(error) });
    }
}
```

I do not think `fetchReviewAlignPerspectivesdCardData` is the reason for the flickering (since it is never called again when the field is updated). I wonder what could be the reason for this problem. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Seems that `

```
export const DATAOPERATION_BEGIN = "DATAOPERATION_BEGIN";
export const dataOperationBegin = () => ({
    type: DATAOPERATION_BEGIN
})
```

This is the reducer code for `case DATAOPERATION_BEGIN`, in which `loading` is set to `true`:

```
 const alignPerspectivesReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
     switch (action.type) {
         case DATAOPERATION_BEGIN:
             return { ...state, loading: true, error: null };
```

I wonder if the way I dispatch `dataOperationBegin` is problematic. Any ideas?

Comment: Use the react developer tools in chrome and see all the events as they happen

Comment: What does `updateCommentSuccess` look like?

Comment: @Andrew very basic: `export const updateCommentSuccess = (normalizedData) => ({
    type: UPDATE_COMMENT_SUCCESS,
    payload: { normalizedData }
})`

Comment: Please tell us which function is fired by the button's `onClick` handler.

Comment: @nbaughman `const onSubmit_updateComment = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    props.updateComment({
        Id: st_activeCommentToEdit,
        Content: st_commentTextEdit,
        UserId: currentUserId
    });
    set_activeCommentToEdit('');
}` i updated the post.

Comment: There's not enough code here to reproduce. [mcve]

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a codesandbox/stackblitz?

Comment: What makes you think the problem is caused somewhere in the code you've included here? Could it be that you are not rendering the form while axios is fetching? If there's a single frame where the component is missing, there might be no scrollbar, and when the component is rendered again a few ms later, the old scrollposition will be lost. What does `dataOperationBegin` do?

Comment: @HåkenLid I found out the line of code causing the problem which is `dispatch(dataOperationBegin());` If i remove it, page is not refreshed. I will post the details in the post.

Comment: @MunimMunna please see the update in the post.

Comment: Look for places in your component or in it's parent components that use the `loading` state. Could you be rendering a loading indicator somewhere while waiting for the axios request to return?

Comment: Inside your component `console.log(props.loading)` is toggling? `false` `true`  `false`. It does doesn't it?

Comment: can you check the `constructor` if it's rebuilding the tree? e.g. `console.log('constructing once')`.

Comment: @Dupocas yes, it does!

Comment: Well then, I believe is mistery solved! I'll analyze when I get home

Comment: Until then, could you please post your code to  `fetchReviewAlignPerspectivesdCardData`?

Comment: @Dupocas probably I will be sleeping because of the timezone, please post your answer so that I can assign the bounty. I will share the code you requested. Thanks!

Comment: @renakre awesome. The problem most certainly lies there

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to reproduce without the full code but it looks like you're accidentally submitting a form, this can be fixed by either setting `<button type="button">...` (because otherwise, it will be a submit button by default) or by setting `e.preventDefault` on the form.